# можно ли убрась всё это в css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<p class="buttond" style="text-align:center;"><a id="download" download="img.jpg" target="_self" style="cursor: pointer; font-size:19px;  text-decoration: none; padding:10px 20px; color:#ffffff; background-color:#0095ff; border-radius:5px; border: 0px solid #0095ff;">download</a>
</p>
```

есть много таких кнопок, как убрать этот ужас в  css?

Comment: Осторожно, стили на эти кнопки могут вешаться скриптом, могут вешаться при генерации кода на сервере скажем. Еще вынеся в цсс вы измените приоритет. Так что проблема может оказаться сложнее чем Вы думаете. Нужен контекст.

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос о том, как сделать это массово, то в гугле есть ссылки на ресурсы, которые могут в этом помочь (например, вот такой https://www.cssout.com/).

Также следует учесть, что inline-стили имеют приоритет над стилями в css-файле. Потому какие-то стили могут перестать работать после удаления их из разметки, так как потеряют важность, и может возникнуть необходимость давать таким стилям `!important`.

Кроме всего прочего, эти стили могут генерироваться на стороне (например, js-скрипты), а потому надо подходить к вопросу осмысленно.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так!

```css
.buttond {
  text-align:center;  
}

#download {
  cursor: pointer; 
  font-size:19px; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  padding:10px 20px; 
  color:#ffffff; 
  background-color:#0095ff; 
  border-radius:5px; 
  border: 0px solid #0095ff;
}
```

```html
<p class="buttond"><a id="download" download="img.jpg" target="_self">download</a>
</p>
```

Comment: спасибо, а почему я не могу присвоить его другой кнопке?#downloadLnk #clear {